# the people of festivals

Tags: word-request

> The Philippines  offers  a  wealth  of  entertainment,  from  classical  plays  to  cultural  shows  and show bands. The people like to celebrate life and their festive spirit is renowned.

According to this context, what  word is suitable for
the question "What kind of people are the Fillipinos?"
My opinion is "the people of festivals".
Is the usage "the people  of festivels" correct with the context?

Answer (score 2):

For me, 'people of festivals' conjures up an image of the people who make a festival come together - the organisers, people who run food stands and such.

I'd use the same adjective found in the original text - festive - and describe them as a *festive people*.